# Best download file with struts 1.1 method

Tags: servlets, download, struts

For a web application built on struts and jsp technologies, I'm looking for a good example which explains how to download files from the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i manage to do it with this few lines of code :
just add this to your action :

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/rtf");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("your_file_path");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
```

Comment: You'll also want to set the content disposition and filename, and return a `null` instead of an `ActionForward` so Struts knows the response was handled within the action. That sure is an old version of Struts.

Comment: yeah , but for actionForward ,why it is not possible to call it ? because in my action i change data in the database and want to return my jsp to display the new data.... any way ?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.